# let a, b, and n be integers. Prove that, if n is a divisor of a - b, then a REM n = b REM n.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am having trouble with proofs involving quotations and remainders. Any suggestion on how to approach these type of proofs?

Comment: Just write everything out.  $a=q_an+r_a,\;b=q_bn+r_b$ so $a-b=\cdots$.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ divides $a-b$, then by definition there is an integer $d$ such that $nd = a - b$. Now $nd$ is a multiple of $n$, so its remainder mod $n$ is $0$. Taking remainders of both sides, we have $(a-b) \equiv 0 \mod n$. Thus $a \equiv b \mod n$.