# Prove that, if n is an integer and n REM 4 = 2, then is not a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So far I have, given that n is an integer we have integers q,b and r such that n = q x b + r. We know N REM 4 = 2. what is the next step?

Comment: Please use proper symbols

Comment: Between this and [your prior questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746018/let-a-b-and-n-be-integers-prove-that-if-n-is-a-divisor-of-a-b-then-a-rem) it looks like you are just posting your homework for us to do for you.  You must have tried something, no?

Comment: The correct statement of the division algorithm is: Given $n$ and $b$ there exist $q$ and $r$ such that $n=qb+r$ and $0 \leq r < b$.  Why do you think that's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Argue by way of contradiction.  Suppose that $n=m^2$.  Now apply the division algorithm to $m,4$ to get $$m=4q+r$$
where $r=0,1,2,3$.  We square $m$ to get $$n=m^2=(4q+r)^2=16q^2+8qr+r^2$$
Now consider each of the four possibilities for $r$, and determine that the result can never be $4k+2$, for  integer $k$.